# 301 redirects rule redirect to wrong URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

When I open my website http://www.codersvolt.com, It redirects to http://www.codersvolt.com/index/ instead of http://www.codersvolt.com/index.php and It should show only http://www.codersvolt.com URL.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.codersvolt.com$1/
```

I am redirecting pages with .html extension to pages without .html extension, Which works fine, but causing above home page issue.

Comment: Do you have any other rules in htaccss?

Comment: No, I have pasted whole htaccess file here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ /$1/
```

Comment: Thanks ! By the way when I open, http://www.codersvolt.com/index.php
It does not remove index.php.